# Por que não podemos usar Await dentro de um Catch, Finally e Synclock no VB?

Tags: .net, vb.net, característica-linguagem, try-catch, assincronismo

Por que não podemos usar o operador `Await` dentro dos *statements* `Catch`, `Finally` e `Synclock` no VB?

O [C# 6.0](http://dailydotnettips.com/2014/12/06/using-await-in-a-catch-or-finally-block-in-c-6-0/) tem suporte para usar o `Await` dentro do `Catch`/`Finally`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não sei te dar uma resposta definitiva sobre isso. Posso dizer que foi porque a linguagem especificou assim. Assim coimo C# havia especificado assim na versão 5. Depois perceberam que podiam relaxar essa restrição, mas não o fizeram o mesmo para o VB.NET. Provavelmente acharam que não compensa. Mas pode ter alguma coisa que o VB.NET permite que pode criar um complicador se usar essa construção. Não saberia informar.

A [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#Anchor_6) fala alguma coisas sobre o método terminar em estado falho e um `await` poderá fazer retornar para esse ponto em falha, o que não deve ser adequado. Mas em C# pode ocorrer o mesmo. O que eu posso especular é que confiaram que o programador C# vai entender isso e saber como usar sem causar maiores problemas. O `synclock` não deixa de ser uma exceção.